# Is there an alternate for an EF Core where clause using List.Contains(object, IEqualityComparer)?

Tags: entity-framework-core

The following syntax will indeed not be translated by EF Core.

```
var books = await context.Books
      .Where(c => detachedBooks.Contains(c, new BookEqualityComparer()))
      .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
      .ToListAsync();
```

I wanted to use a separate BookEqualityComparer here in order not to inherit from IEquatable in Entity Book so as not to interfere with the regular working of EF Core.

*detachedBooks* is a list of detached Book entities, i.e. the Id are not available.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your class implements `IEquatable` or not - it won't be used by EF Core because (1) it needs to generate SQL criteria and (2) it can translate to SQL only `Contains` with primitive values. for the same reason it does not support passing `IEqualityComparer`. Reference: [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works) in EF Core docs

Answer (score 1):

I doubt anything that complex would be ever supported in EF. Select your relevant details from your detached entities or DTOs and use those. For instance something like this would generally match rows based on their PKs or elements of a composite key:

```
var bookIds = detachedBooks.Select(x => x.BookId).ToList();
var books = await context.Books
    .Where(c => bookIds.Contains(c.BookId))
    .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: How would you write this if you wanted to test over several Properties instead of the BookId ?

Comment: It would depend on exactly what you want to do. The example you had implied that the detachedBooks were simply detached book entities that you wanted to load fresh copies of, so the best way forward there would be to fetch by ID. If instead you passed something like a list of author names and publishing years the logic would depend on how you want those criteria applied. In some cases it might be best to filter on one property to load an encompassing sub-set of data, then further filter based on the additional property. (I.e. filter on Author, then further drill down by year or years.)